# sorting and filtering pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, pivot-table

Using this data

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
df=pd.read_excel(
    "https://github.com/chris1610/pbpython/blob/master/data/sample-salesv3.xlsx?raw=True"
    )
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

I used the next code to get Year, month and day :

```
df['year'],df['month'],df['day'] = df.date.dt.year, df.date.dt.month, df.date.dt.day

   account number                         name       sku  quantity  \
0          740150                   Barton LLC  B1-20000        39   
1          714466              Trantow-Barrows  S2-77896        -1   
2          218895                    Kulas Inc  B1-69924        23   
3          307599  Kassulke, Ondricka and Metz  S1-65481        41   
4          412290                Jerde-Hilpert  S2-34077         6   

   unit price  ext price                date  year  month  day  
0       86.69    3380.91 2014-01-01 07:21:51  2014      1    1  
1       63.16     -63.16 2014-01-01 10:00:47  2014      1    1  
2       90.70    2086.10 2014-01-01 13:24:58  2014      1    1  
3       21.05     863.05 2014-01-01 15:05:22  2014      1    1  
4       83.21     499.26 2014-01-01 23:26:55  2014      1    1
```

Then I used the next code to get pivot table

```
df.pivot_table(index=['year','month','name'],values='ext price',aggfunc=np.sum).head(25)


                                         ext price
year month name                                      
2014 1     Barton LLC                         6177.57
           Cronin, Oberbrunner and Spencer    1141.75
           Frami, Hills and Schmidt           5112.34
           Fritsch, Russel and Anderson      15130.77
           Halvorson, Crona and Champlin      9997.17
           Herman LLC                        10749.84
           Jerde-Hilpert                     11274.33
           Kassulke, Ondricka and Metz        7322.83
           Keeling LLC                        6847.86
           Kiehn-Spinka                       8097.50
           Koepp Ltd                         10768.33
           Kuhn-Gusikowski                    7309.54
           Kulas Inc                         15398.87
           Pollich LLC                        1004.22
           Purdy-Kunde                        4689.37
           Sanford and Sons                   9544.13
           Stokes LLC                         5809.34
           Trantow-Barrows                   14328.26
           White-Trantow                     13703.77
           Will LLC                          20953.87
     2     Barton LLC                        12218.03
           Cronin, Oberbrunner and Spencer   13976.26
           Frami, Hills and Schmidt           4124.53
           Fritsch, Russel and Anderson       9595.35
           Halvorson, Crona and Champlin      7082.15
```

I wonder if I can edit my pivot table to get and ***sort*** only  the **top 5 `name` (top `ext price`)** for each month.

I'm trying to get this :

```
year month name                                      
2014 1     Barton LLC                         6177.57
           Cronin, Oberbrunner and Spencer    1141.75
           Frami, Hills and Schmidt           5112.34
           Fritsch, Russel and Anderson      15130.77
           Halvorson, Crona and Champlin      9997.17
     2     Barton LLC                        12218.03
           Cronin, Oberbrunner and Spencer   13976.26
           Frami, Hills and Schmidt           4124.53
           Fritsch, Russel and Anderson       9595.35
           Halvorson, Crona and Champlin      7082.15
...                                               ...
     11    Koepp Ltd                          4882.27
           Kuhn-Gusikowski                    7197.89
           Kulas Inc                          4149.34
           Pollich LLC                        6334.21
     12    Barton LLC                         2772.90
           Cronin, Oberbrunner and Spencer    7640.60
           Frami, Hills and Schmidt          16249.81
           Fritsch, Russel and Anderson      12345.64
```

I've tried to use groupby with sorting but still can't find it.

Comment: In the future, please post your sample data directly and your desired output as well.

Comment: I've tried but output was not really clear, I don't know how to select data from jupyter

Comment: check out the `to_clipboard` dataframe method. It makes stackexchange copy/pasting a breeze when combined with `from_clipboard`. e.g. you can get sample data easily with something like `df.sample(20).to_clipboard()`.

Comment: Thank you, it's really useful, I've modified the question

Comment: After your edit, it looks like `<<pivot_table_code>>.reset_index().groupby(['year, 'month']).head(5)` is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
>>> df.sort_values('ext price', ascending = False).groupby(
['year', 'month']).head(5).set_index(['year', 'month'])['name']


year  month
2014  7                           Kiehn-Spinka
      7                        Kuhn-Gusikowski
      12                             Koepp Ltd
      7                            Pollich LLC
      3                              Kulas Inc
      2                             Barton LLC
      3                            Keeling LLC
      10                             Koepp Ltd
      7                        Trantow-Barrows
      9            Kassulke, Ondricka and Metz
```